# How do I calculate light transmittance given the absorption coefficient and thickness of the medium?

Tags: visible-light, absorption

I would like to know the percentage of light that makes it through a glass pane, and I'm given the absorption coefficient and the thickness of the glass.  The glass is non-reflective if that helps any.

I've looked up things about the Beer-Lambert law, but from what I can tell I need the transmitted intensity and the received intensity of the light (which I do not have).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Reflective or not you will still need to know the angle of incidents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radiation thru a medium is given by the equation $$ I = I_0exp(-\mu_a x) $$ where $\mu$ is the attenuation coefficient for the particular type of radiation (light in your case), x is thickness of the attenuator (glass in your case), I is the resulting intensity and Io is the initial intensity. You can write this as $$ \frac{I}{I_0} = exp(-\mu_0x)$$ where $\frac{I}{I_0} $ gives you the percent attenuation.

I assume the absorption coefficient and what I called the attenuation coefficient are the same. So you should have all you need.